# Facebook pull feeds

Tags: facebook

I need to "watch" some facebook pages (public pages) and every time there is a new post (en each one of the pages) to be able to get it and store it in my database.
I've found the "real time updates" on facebook developer page (`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/`) but this is not exacly what I need. To use this "push updates" you need to create a Facebook app and users to give access to it.
I only need to watch public pages (so no authentication needed).
The other solution is to use  somethiong like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed?access_token=mytoken
```

but this means to query facebook server every x seconds. I don't know if facebook has some limitation.

Does anybody know the better solution to accomplish that ?

I've been searching for a while but I did not found the proper solution.

Thanks.

Comment: There does not seem to be a request-per-time limit, so you should be OK with polling Facebook regularly if Real-Time Updating is not the way you want to go.